# Take 4:3 photos with AVFoundation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I've made a custom camera for my App and I use `AVFoundation` with an `AVCaptureSession` to let the user take photos.
Now, the video stream coming from the camera is what seems like 16:9 so they can only take 16:9 photos.
I'm not sure how the iPhone's own App handles this (images **4:3**, video **16:9** - do they zoom in?) but I want to do the same.
Not cutting the image afterwards or so, I want the true 4:3 signal that would show in the camera App. (correct me if Apple does exactly that... :D)
Tell me if you need code or so but it's basically the standard AVCaptureSession with an AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: //the camera) added as input.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be able to control the image by setting the `AVCaptureSession`'s `sessionPreset` property. I believe setting this to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` should do what you want. But if that doesn't work, by all means do post the code and I'll take a look